# How do we test error and failure cases with Google Pay?

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

I'm using Google Pay with Stripe on Android.

I'm part of the testing Google group, so I have the list of Google Pay test cards that I can test with, but they all succeed. I've been unable to add Stripe's cards that give specific failures to Google Pay.

I'd like to be able to test failing for insufficient funds for example, where the card is valid, it just fails to actually charge.

I've been able to reproduce some of the errors in production, for example by using a card with a $0 balance, but I have to do this on a release build and don't have access to the debugger, which makes tracking down issues a lot harder.

What's the best approach for testing all the various failure cases with Google Pay?

EDIT: I'm able to mock responses and do testing that way, but the errors in production don't seem to act the way the documentation would lead me to believe, so I'm having trouble mocking in a way that actually matches production behavior. Would be nice to be able to end-to-end test with Stripe's test cards in Google pay for example.

Comment: Regarding issues with mocking responses, is it fair to assume that your application also has a regular checkout form where you capture regular card numbers for users who don't use Google Pay? If so, I would expect Stripe's responses for typical card processing to be similar to the Google Pay payment token. Are you able to use the same response from Stripe for card processing and Google Pay?

Comment: Currently we're just using Google Pay to capture card info. I'll probably incorporate a standard card checkout at some point, might even feature toggle it off and just use it for testing, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Google Pay won't typically return information related to things like insufficient funds. The reason is Google Pay will perform some authorization checks when the card is added to Google Pay, but not when the user selects a payment method.

When a user selects a payment method with Google Pay, it returns a payment token that you would then pass onto your PSP (Stripe) and Stripe would respond with insufficient funds (and other scenarios). Therefore, it comes down to how your Stripe integration responds with the payment data specified. My suggestion is to stub/mock the request to Stripe and return your desired response instead. The response from Stripe would typically need to be handled in your back-end code and sent to your Android app with details of the failure (e.g. insufficient funds).

Comment: Right, I was hoping to find something that allows an end-to-end test like Stripe normally allows with their test cards. I've been able to mock the behaviors just fine, but I'm not seeing the expected behavior for these scenarios in production.

Comment: That's actually a very reasonable use case. I'll pass the feedback onto the team.